# Не могу загрузить все списки из базы при помощи Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

Доброго времени суток. Есть Person c Blogs в нем http://prntscr.com/gd208r
При помощи Include() загружаю из EF блоги http://prntscr.com/gd263c но списки (Likes, Comment, View)  null хотя в базе лайки есть. Как загрузить все списки?

Comment: Минус посту за оформление: код не прикладывают картинками, код постят текстом.

Comment: А где аналогичные инклюды для всего остального?!

Answer (score 1):

Используй `Include()` и `ThenInclude()`. В твоем случае:

```
var items = dbTest.Persons.Include(p => p.Blogs).ThenInclude(b => b.Likes).ToList();
```

**P.S:** не советую так делать. Представь: есть 50 пользователей, у каждого по 200 постов, на каждом посте по 1000 лайков. Размер json-файла?)

Comment: Огромная благодарность Ares God в отличии от дизайнера первого коммента и капитана очевидности  второго комментария. Жаль рейтинг не могу поставить.

Comment: @РоманПетров: 1. было бы неплохо отредактировать вопрос: привести код **текстом** а не **картинкой**. 2. Если мой вопрос в комменте был для Вас не новостью(о необходимости использовать `Include`), то вопроса как такого не должно быть. ходя судя по тому что ответ Вам помог у Вас EF7(о чем в вопросе кстати не слова)